# Simplifying polygon

Tags: qgis

I am trying to simplify the overlaying polygon (green). Aim is to fill the area which is marked orange (underlaying polygon). Which tool can I use? I have tried v.generalize and v.clean but none seem to have the algorithm I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried joining and dissolving both layers?

Comment: If it is a one of that you could enable tracing and use the reshape feature tool when editing the feature.

Answer (score 2):

If the orange area is stored in a layer you can use the union tool to generate an output with the coverage area of both the green and the orange layers. See http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Union for a full explanation of the tool.

Answer (score 2):

If it is for visualization purpose, apply the new colour to the underlying orangle layer which however apply it to whole Orange polygon layer including the area/polygon spread beneath green colour polygon.

Other way, use the subtract/different function between Green polygon and Orange Polygon which should generate the new layer which contains only the orange area highlighted in your picture. Subtract/difference function is available in most of the GIS software under Geoprocessing options.